# Show all hidden row using JS without jquery

Tags: javascript

How can I show all the hidden rows without jQuery? I try this:

```
var testElements = document.getElementsByClassName('tr1');
var testDivs = Array.prototype.filter.call(testElements, function (testElement) {
    testElement.style.visibility = 'visible';
});
```

But nothing happens. What can I do?

Comment: Your code works: https://jsfiddle.net/awx0rr1L/. How are the elements hidden?If you used `display: none`, then you need to set the `display` property, not `visibility`

Comment: Rory thanks, what I have to set in display:  testElement.style.display = ?

Comment: testElement.style.display = 'block'

Comment: As @a.u.b says, it's `display = 'block'` you need to use: https://jsfiddle.net/awx0rr1L/1/

Comment: thanks to all! I set :testElement.style.display = ""; and it works

Comment: You have already got the answers .But I would strongly recommend to use jquery - because its like `Code Less , Do More.` 
same thing you can do by code like `$('.tr1').show();`  thats it